# How to handle inconsistencies caused by data duplication in Cassandra?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, data-modeling

I'm new to Cassandra. From data modeling standpoint, we design tables around query patterns/use cases over traditional RDBMS way. We prefer duplication of data to achieve high scalability and avoid joins. For instance say, if we have to model movie database with query patterns to search movie based on Genre, search movie based on ratings. We create two different tables say, (MovieByGenre, MovieByRatings) and duplicate same movie details into both both tables.

In such scenario, how to handle adding of new movies and updating existing ones. Do I need to add/update all the tables on each add/update request?

I used movie database example just for demonstrating duplication scenario. It may not be the appropriate design.

Comment: This answer may give you some idea about denormalization and practices around it. There are several useful links in the answer too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282905/2188922

Answer (score 0):

I think Ersoy's comment has good information so please refer to that for a detailed answer.

But, just to respond to the specific question within your post: Yes, you do need to update all the `MovieBy*` tables when adding new movies, updating existing movies, and deleting old movies.